# In Elm, why is this an Int-Float type mismatch?

Tags: elm

I am new to elm, and functional programming in general.  I was getting a puzzling type mismatch when doing division with a call to 'show'.  This code produces the mismatch:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)

columns = 2
main = placePiece 10

placePiece: Int -> Element
placePiece index =
  show (index/columns)
```

The code produces this error:

> Type mismatch between the following types on line 9, column 3 to 22:
>
> ```
>   Int
>
>   Float
> ```
>
> It is related to the following expression:
>
> ```
>   show (index / columns)
> ```

Which I read to mean that it expects and Int, but got a Float.  But show works with any type.  If I use floor to force the division into an Int, I get the same error.  But, if I hard code the numbers, e.g. `show (10/2)` It works fine.

So what part of the code above is expecting to get an Int?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Reason for the error

Actually in this case the compiler is expecting a `Float` but getting an `Int`. The `Int` is the argument `index` of the `placePiece` function, and it expects a `Float` because [`Basics.(/)`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Basics#/) expects `Float` arguments.

## Why literal numbers work

When you just hard code numbers, the compiler can figure out that although you're using whole numbers, you may want to use them as `Float` instead of `Int`.

## Fixing the error

There are three ways to fix this error. If you really want to accept an Int but want floating point division, you'll have to turn the integer into a floating point number:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)

columns = 2
main = placePiece 10

placePiece: Int -> Element
placePiece index =
  show (toFloat index / columns)
```

If you're ok with the `placePiece` function taking a floating point number you can change the type signature:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)

columns = 2
main = placePiece 10

placePiece: Float -> Element
placePiece index =
  show (index/columns)
```

If you wanted integer division, you can use the [`Basics.(//)`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Basics#//) operator:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)

columns = 2
main = placePiece 10

placePiece: Int -> Element
placePiece index =
  show (index//columns)
```

Comment: In this case I wanted integer division, so the third option was perfect.  Thanks also for the explanation of why literals worked.  I thought the compiler would only interpret a literal as a float if you put something like `x=1.0`, with hard coded decimal place.